# APC SC1000I over USB and NUT

Tags: apc-smart-ups, nut

I've got an [APC SC1000I](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SC1000I) which I want to set up to be monitored with **NUT**, likely with **newhidups**.
The basic config doesn't work:

```
# tail -n 1 /var/log/messages
Poll UPS [apc@localhost] failed - Driver not connected
```

What puzzles me, is that the UPS connected over USB is detected as

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

Is it possible to monitor this given UPS with NUT at all? A working **ups.conf** section would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I've a SmartUPS 1500 and a BackUPS XS 1500 both plugged into a system and monitored by NUT. The BackUPS uses the *usbhid-ups* driver; the SmartUPS uses the *apcsmart* driver. Here's the section of `ups.conf` that contains both UPSes:

```
[apc1]
  driver = usbhid-ups
  port = auto
  desc = "BackUPS XS 1500 on rack top"

[apc2]
  driver = apcsmart
  port = /dev/ttyS0
  desc = "SmartUPS 1500 in rack"
```

You may want to use better names than these, though.

Note that in both cases these require a special cable. Two things to note about the SmartUPS (which APC seems to think your UPS is) - the serial cable is a special cable, and if the UPS was used with a serial cable before, then the USB port is essentially shut off. To reset the selected port, you'll have to perform some magic with the UPS.